# What makes the dot not displaying right in the middle of the circle border

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm trying to customise a radio button that has a border of 1px and a gap of 1px between the dot (plain circle) and the border. My problem is that the gap is not displaying evenly. Wierdly, when I change the border and the padding from 1px to 2px, it works. Why is that?

[image: see here]

### SCSS

```
.radio {
  &__input {
    display: none;
  }

  &__custom {
    padding: 1px;
    border: 1px solid lightgray;
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    
    &::after {
      content: '';
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      display: block;
      background-color: blue;
      border-radius: 50%;
    }
  }
}
```

### HTML

```html
<label htmlFor="testRadio" className='radio'>
    <input id='testRadio'type="radio" className='radio__input'/>
    <div className='radio__custom'></div>
</label>
```

Comment: Hi There ! Welcome to SO. Kindly share your HTML code as well :) We need to how are the classes written :)

Comment: browser can easily divide 2px to 1px but when it comes to 1px you will face rounding issue

Comment: @ImranRafiqRather Voilà, I just added the HTML :)

Comment: It seems perfect to me. Probable any other style added to your react component or the root component is affecting it. Codepen: https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/vYXQzqv

Comment: @Dear Manas My Friend.. It's a simple HTML page :-) Let's try to fix the issue for the OP :)

Comment: @Marilyn Dufour : Great let me have a look :)

Comment: @MarilynDufour Which browser are you seeing this in? It looks OK to me as well in Firefox and Chrome. Working with `em`s can sometimes produce some strange rounding errors, although usually only if you use small decimals, e.g., `0.2em`.

Comment: @ImranRafiqRather I use Chrome.

Comment: @ManasKhandelwal I still see the problem on your Codepen (thanks!), so it means that the problem is not in the code itself but maybe the way the machine renders it...

Comment: @MarilynDufour I also see no problem in Codepen :) I see a rounded small radio button, but it fits perfectly as it should :)

Comment: @MarilynDufour See this: https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/vYXQzqv. I have increased the size and I still do not see off centre.

Comment: @MarilynDufour Did you zoom in to take the screenshot, or are you using a non-integer display scale? If you're using Windows or Linux, your UI scale could be set to 150% or something, which could cause weird alignment like this.

Comment: @MarilynDufour This is what it looks like to us in 400% zoom: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PtmCC.png

Comment: @Blieque That's it. When I adjust the scale at 100% on my computer it solves the problem even if I am zooming in the browser after.

Answer (score 0):

*To summarise the comments on the question...*

The issue was caused by rounding of logical measurements to physical pixel measurments performed by the browser. This rounding is required for non-`px` units, and also `px` units when UI scale is not 100%.

If you're seeing a similar issue to OP:

- **Check your OS display scale.** This is best kept to a multiple a of 100% or 1×, e.g., "300%", "2×". It will already be for most users, so you can keep your preferred UI scale while knowing that most users will see the UI correctly.
- **Check your CSS units.** Using `em` units or subdivisions of units, like `0.2rem`, can also cause rounding quirks. I've noticed this particularly with `box-shadow` in Firefox.
- **Try another browser.** As mentioned, these quirks can vary between different rendering engines. Try Firefox, Chrome, or Safari if you haven't.